# Why Clang supports dereferencing uninitialized pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to understand what happened to my knowledge of C programming. Let's start with a CLASSICAL problem (dereferencing uninitialized pointer):

```
int main( void ) {
    char *p;
    *p = 'a';
    printf( "%c\n", *p );
    return 0;
}
```

This is obviously WRONG! I know it. However, when I ran this on my MacOS 10.12 with LLVM Clang 8.1.0 implemented as compiler, it not only failed to detect uninitialized pointer, but also displayed the character 'a' on the screen, as if nothing was wrong. At least I expect something like "Segmentation Fault".

Please hold your thought and bear with me a moment to see the following code:

```
int main( void ) {
    int i;
    char **strPtr;
    char *string = "Hello, world!";

    *strPtr = string;

    printf( "%s", *strPtr );
    return 0;
}
```

This time, I ran the code with GCC-4.8.5 which has successfully detected the segmentation fault in the first code. To my dismay, the string "Hello, world!" appeared on the screen after I ran the code as if nothing was wrong with it.

I wonder, since strPtr is also a pointer (though a pointer to pointer), by dereferencing and assigning value to strPtr, shouldn't I commit the same fault as I did in the first code?

Comment: Tell your clang that you want it to warn you about such stuff (`-Wall`), and that it should consider such warnings errors (`-Werror`). In other words, use e.g. `clang -Wall -Werror source.c -o binary`.

Comment: Your pointer is not uninitialised. And any god compiler, including clang will warn about a nonsensical conversion. It s not the compiler's fault if you ignore them (or don't enable the recommended warnings)

Comment: "but also displayed the result" - which result? That code does not make any sense, but invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: When you write a program that invokes undefined behavior, which yours does, _any_ behavior is "correct" with respect to the C standard. Seg faults aren't guaranteed.  You'd get a seg fault if the junk contents of `p` happened to be an address not within a valid segment of the program. As luck would have it, the junk contents of `p` in your case happened to point to read/write memory allocated to your program.

Comment: Truly, compilers' divergence in undefined behaviors explains the question, but how would you enlighten me with the 2nd pice of code?

Comment: @DragScorpio: Which part of `-Wall -Werror` did you miss? If you do not specify any options to the compiler, the compilers default to their own settings, which in many cases is not even standard C. GCC, for example, defaults to a GNU dialect of C. The behaviour you want or expect, you can only get from gcc and clang if you use `-Wall -Werror` options.

Comment: @Nominal Animal: Thanks,  -Wall -Werror options did filter the error out. I did not used the options before.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't *support* it; it's just that the compiler assumes that you know what you are doing.

It's just that the behaviour on dereferencing an unintialised pointer is *undefined*.

It appearing to work is a manifestation of that undefined behaviour.

Remember the old maxim: C gives you the ability to shoot yourself in the foot.